# Getopt multiple argument syntaxes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, getopt

So I'm working on an assignment in a python class that I'm taking, but have gotten stuck with something I can't really find any further information about (neither on SO, Google or in the courseware).

I need help with how to handle arguments with multiple types of syntaxes - like  **[arg] and < arg >**, which is something I've been unable to find any further information about.

Here is an example use-case that SHOULD work.

```
>>> ./marvin-cli.py --output=<filename.txt> ping <http://google.com>
>>> Syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

The below code works fine for any use-case where I haven't defined any further output than writing to the console:

```
# Switch through all options
try:

    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hsv", ["help","version","silent", "get=", "ping=", "verbose", "input=", "json"])
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            printUsage(EXIT_SUCCESS)
        elif opt in ("-s", "--silent"):
            VERBOSE = False 
        elif opt in ("--verbose"):
            VERBOSE = True 
        elif opt in ("--ping"):
            ping(arg)
        elif opt in ("--input"):
            print("Printing to: ", arg)
        else:
            assert False, "Unhandled option"


except Exception as err:
    print("Error " ,err)
    print(MSG_USAGE)
    # Prints the callstack, good for debugging, comment out for production
    #traceback.print_exception(Exception, err, None)
    sys.exit(EXIT_USAGE)
#print(sys.argv[1])
```

Example usage:

```
>>> ./marvin-cli.py ping http://google.com
>>> Latency 100ms
```

And this is a snippet showing how the ping works:

```
def ping(URL):
    #Getting necessary imports
    import requests
    import time

    #Setting up variables
    start = time.time()
    req = requests.head(URL)
    end = time.time()

    #printing result
    if VERBOSE == False:
        print("I'm pinging: ", URL)
        print("Received HTTP response (status code): ", req.status_code)

    print("Latency: {}ms".format(round((end - start) * 1000, 2)))
```

Comment: what is your question exactly? do you want to add `--output` to your getopt parsing?

Comment: I thought the question was obvious... I need to handle multiple argument syntaxes where the argument(s) should be in both / either [] or <>

Comment: Are you required to use `getopt`? Because `argparse` is a lot more powerful while offering a great syntax for these cases, without you having to parse it all yourself.

Comment: @poke sadly it's an intro course to programming so we are required to use specific libraries, even if it would be more friendly / powerful... :/

Comment: I'm sorry but this is stupid: `./marvin-cli.py --output=<filename.txt>`. It would try to redirect output and input because of the `<>` symbols. What is the difference for you between `[]` and `<>`, even if it's obvious to you. ?

Comment: That's the problem, isn't it? I'm asking here because it ISN'T obvious to me and I'm hoping for people to tell me how to figure it out, regardless of if it's 'stupid' or not. I'm not in charge of the class and such can't be picky about the assignment. 
For me, there is no clear difference but having us students use different ways of tackling parsing and it makes even less sense to have any sort of parsing.
Do you have any answer to the question that I asked, or are you just going to tell me how stupid the question is? :)

Comment: Are you *really* supposed to put argument values inside `<>`? That sounds very unlikely to me. And we still have no idea what the difference between `[]` and `<>` arguments is supposed to be.

Comment: Well, either the professor is completely incoherent when speaking / writing his native tongue, or that is how we are supposed to be writing some use cases. 
Certain ones should handle a simple opt arg structure and there should be one with opt [arg] as well as one with opt <arg>
No clear indication on what the difference should be between them at all.

Comment: Well, if the assignment is unclear, you should ask your professor to clarify it. There is not much we can do if the assignment is bad.

Comment: [] and <> are used to document requirements. Typically [] means optional and <> required.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` and `<>` are commonly used to visually indicate option requirement. Typically `[xxxx]` means the option or argument is optional and `<xxxx>` required.

The sample code you provide handles option flags, but not the required arguments. Code below should get you started in the right direction.

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hsv", ["help", "version", "silent", "verbose", "output=", "json"])
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            printUsage(EXIT_SUCCESS)
        elif opt in ("-s", "--silent"):
            VERBOSE = False 
        elif opt in ("--verbose"):
            VERBOSE = True
        elif opt in ("--output"):
            OUTPUTTO = arg
            print("Printing to: ", arg)
        else:
            assert False, "Unhandled option"

    assert len(args) > 0, "Invalid command usage"
    # is there a "<command>" function defined?
    assert args[0] in globals(), "Invalid command {}".format(args[0])

    # pop first argument as the function to call
    command = args.pop(0)
    # pass args list to function
    globals()[command](args)


def ping(args):
    #Getting necessary imports
    import requests
    import time

    # validate arguments
    assert len(args) != 1, "Invalid argument to ping"
    URL = args[0]

    #Setting up variables
    start = time.time()
    req = requests.head(URL)
    end = time.time()

    #printing result
    if VERBOSE == False:
        print("I'm pinging: ", URL)
        print("Received HTTP response (status code): ", req.status_code)

    print("Latency: {}ms".format(round((end - start) * 1000, 2)))
```